# window outerHeight is 1024 on ipad

Tags: ios, web-applications, ipad-2

I'm working  on a webapp for ios and android.  The orientation is landscape when its run on a tablet.

When the app runs on an android tablet, the style file included is right, but when the app runs on an iPad 2, the style file included is  wrong.

Then I get an alert `window.outerHeight` and `window.outer` on an android tablet, and it's 768 and 1024. Except I get 1024 and 1024 on ipad2. it should be `768` and `1024`.

Here is the meta tag:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta content="black" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" />
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
```

How  do I set `window.outerHeight` to 768 on an iPad 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
```

I've had this problem, and for me it was in the viewport meta tag (height=device-height). The only other suspicious one in your code seems to be

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
```